# How do I make it so I can have a sidebar and text right next to the side bar in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

So I have a side bar I made using a table (someone told me to do that)

But my issue is this: http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/pXWxFx9.png

As you can see that red circle is my sidebar, but when I put my other text (the one in the blue circle) it goes under the table/div I have for my sidebar.

How can I make it so the text in the blue circle can move to the blue square that you see in the image.

This is my code for my sidebar.

```
    <div class="border1">
    <div style= "color:yellow; font-size: 20px;">Why choose us?</div>
    <br>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="font-size:15px;">
      <td style="width: 20%;color:white;">we are a 100% free service,
      <br> we will never ask for a credit card. 
      <br> we will live chat with you if you want, 
      <br> and we update you frequently!
      <br>
      <br>
      we will never force the person to say things to make it look like they are willing to cheat, we will simply talk and get to know them and bring things up and see how it goes, and it will all be reported back to you!
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
            <p style="color:yellow; font-size:20px"> Live Chat! </p>
            we also have a live chat client built in the website so you can talk live with a staff member about any questions or concerns you have prior to making a request,
            <br>
                even if it says live chat is offline it will send us a notification and we will see it, so don't hesitate to use the chat.</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

This is my css class code for my side bar

```
.border1 {

    width: 170px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 15px green;
    margin: 20px;
```

The code for my part I want next to the side bar

```
<div class=border2>
    <p style="color:white;"> fgynjtufjkftguykhfk.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
            <h1 style="color:yellow;"> How to make a request </h1>
            <p style="color:white;"> fycjfyxcjxcgjnyf</p>
            <p style="color:white;"> 
                Yhbdxtht (first):
                <br>
                pthdxhe (first and last):
                <br>
                partaccounts (fill outdchx below)
                <br>
                <br>
                Factk:hxd
                <br>
                Twrxhr:
                <br>
                ktdshk:
                <br>
                wtdhdt:
                <br>
                stdshat:
                <br>
                anydthhtthey use:
                <br>
                xthrfhdxzhxchtample: facebook, kik, ect..):
                <br>
                <br>
                any questions for us?:
                <br>
                <br>
                </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to steer away from inline styling.

Comment: Yes, what @Utkanos said. Whilst working you could use a `<style>` tag, which makes it easier to transfer it into a CSS file later on.

Comment: any idea how i make them go next each other then my sidebar acting as it takes up the middle black space?

Comment: just look at the pic i linked, i want the blue circle to go where the blue square is

Answer (score 0):

this is how i fixed it

```
    div1 {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}

.div2 {
    float:left;
    width:70%;
```